# Does "boulevard" etymologically derive from "bouleverser"?

Tags: étymologie, origine-ou-raison

Does [*boulevard*](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/query?report=bibliography&filename=Littre.*&head=boulevard) etymologically derive from [*bouleverser*](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/query?report=bibliography&filename=Littre.*&head=bouleverser)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No dictionary considers *boulevard* derives from *bouleverser*. Their history is also quite different.

*[Boulevard](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/boulevard)* comes from the Dutch *bolwerc* and/or the Middle High German *bolwërc* meaning "bastion", "[bulwark](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bulwark)" (fortification, small fort).

*[Bouleverser](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/bouleverser)* was coined in old French from the verbs *[bouler](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/bouler)* (overturn with a ball) and *[verser](http://micmap.org/dicfro/next/dictionnaire-godefroy/206/8/verser)* (spill).

Ultimately, the root for the first part of these words (*boule...*) is likely to be the same though, since you have the Old German *bol*: "bowl" and the Latin *bulla*: "bubble". Both refer to round objects and derive from the reconstructed Proto-Indo-European root [*bʰel-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/b%CA%B0el-) (“to blow, inflate, swell”).

Comment: *verser* is closer to "pour" than to "spill" (that would be *renverser*). Maybe it's different in old French, is that what you meant?

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Yes, *verser* had more meanings in old French (*renverser, précipiter, abattre, déborder, tourner...*)